Why do I get "Subscript requires that Float conform to Value" when I try to select a field of type Float?
With SQLite.swift 0.15.3 in XCode 16 I'm trying to select a field of type Float but I get an error assigning it a variable. The field is defined as let iAmount = Expression<Float>("Amount");. When I try to populate a variable I get:

Subscript 'subscript(_:)' requires that 'Float' conform to 'Value'

The code:
for ri in try db.prepare(dtRecipeIngredients.order(iName).where(iUUIDRecipe == r[rUUID]))
{
let amount : Float = ri[iAmount]

let newIngredient = Ingredient (
    Name: ri[iName]
    , Qnty: amount
)

The error occurs at compile time, not run time. Should I be declaring the expression for the field in a different way for a Float? I'm able to use String and Data type.

Did you try Double? https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#building-type-safe-sql

Swift Float simply doesn't conform to Value (this is a protocol declared by SQLite.swift).
Use Double instead, which does conform to Value. This makes sense, because floating point numbers in SQLite are always 8 bytes.
let iAmount = Expression<Double>("Amount")

You can convert it to a Float after you get the column's value if you like,
let amount = Float(ri[iAmount])

